# I have discovered(?) a spiral pattern in stacked snub cubes.

Tags: geometry, 3d, polyhedra

I really hope I don't sound crazy.

I was messing around with different geometric shapes for inspiration for a fictional alien creature I am designing, and I noticed something odd about snub cubes that I'm not sure have ever been noticed before. If you overlap stack them (also they have to be the same size) so that the center of each snub cube is roughly 10.87448 units above the previous snub cube, and rotate each successive snub cube by roughly 327.0919 degrees, the square faces will form a spiral pattern. Somewhere in this post there should be an image demonstrating the spiral pattern.

[image]

I don't see anything about this on Google or DuckDuckGo, so have I seriously discovered something new about an Archimedean solid?

Comment: Snub cubes are chiral. So stacking them creates a spiral pattern.

Comment: Nifty. (Technically, the squares form a [*helix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helix), not a *spiral*.) It's a nice pattern, but such things are to be expected when you translate-and-rotate stuff. Note, for instance, that your stack contains reverse-helices formed by equilateral triangles, too. ... Cheers!

Comment: Indeed, as pointed by Blue, if you make a Google query with "**helix** patterns polyhedra" you get a lot of results.